# why i am not able to checkout to razorpay?

Tags: android

Below error shows in log

E/PaymentActivity: Error in starting Razorpay Checkout
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)

Comment: Seems like there's a `println` without a message ... but without your code we cannot tell.

Comment: throwing exception while checkout for this call --checkout.open(activity, options); not used any println in code. i refer it from the official site .. can u plz suggest is becuase of key id?

Comment: it seems there is some issue your facing with android SDK import. please find a demo app here - https://github.com/ayush-razorpay/android-sdk